# Adding extra info in form field and use it while rendering django template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add extra infos for some fields of a django form, and use it in templates to add some extra html tags

I've a django form like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    integer = forms.IntegerField(
        help_text='Please enter your favorite integer number',
        label='Favorite integer',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    decimal = forms.DecimalField(
        min_value=Decimal('0.0001'),
        decimal_places=4,
        help_text='Please enter your favorite decimal number',
        label='Favorite decimal',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-xlarge'}))
    ==> here I would like to say: decimal will have a new property
```

I am rendering MyForm in a template, using a loop over each field:

```
{% for item in form.visible_fields %}
  ==> here I would like to test if item has that property to add some html tags
  {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

I cannot use the widget's attrs, as I want to use the property info outside the rendered input tag.

Should I [create a custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields), write custom renderers for all fields I use, or is there a simpler solution I did miss ?

---

Edit: So far my solution is :  (simplified version)
Main template:

```
<form action="/somewhere/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 {% include 'form_field.html' with item=form.integer icon="icon-home" %}
 {% include 'form_field.html' with item=form.decimal icon="icon-list-alt" %}
 {% include 'form_field.html' with item=form.another icon="icon-signal" %}
 {% include 'form_field.html' with item=form.again   icon="icon-time" %}
 ...
```

In form_field.html, I render a field using [Twitter's Bootstrap input-prepend div](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons):

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="{{ item.name }}">{{ item.label }}</label>
  <div class="controls">
    {% if icon %}
      <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="{{ icon }}"></i></span>
    {% endif %}
      {{ item }}
      <p class="help-block">{{ item.help_text }}</p>
    {% if icon %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

All I want is to simplify the main template, using a loop rather enumerating all fields, which is error prone. So I want to move that 'icon-home' property from the template to the form definition, to have all attributes in the same place (specific widget attrs are already in the form). 
Ideally, in the main template I would have:

```
{% for item in form.visible_fields %}
  {% include 'form_field.html' %}
{% endfor %}
```

I understand it can be viewed as a misunderstanding of Django's principles (site look should be in templates, not in forms)...

Comment: Can you elaborate on and explain in a high-level of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've added some precisions in comments on Paul's response. Does it clarifies ?

Comment: Next time when you add additional info to your question, like clarification, make sure you add it to the original post rather than in comments. That way you have all of the info in one place. Not to mention you can present the info better with rich-formatting capability, which is not offered in comments.

Comment: "want to have a 'prepend' icon for some of my fields". Are these fields all of the same form field type?

Comment: no, I've CharField, ChoiceField, IntegerField and DecimalField

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Custom form field** + **multiple inheritance** + **a class that stores the icon class name**

First, let's define a class that captures the icon class name. We'll call it *IconName*:

```
class IconName(object):
    def get_icon_name(self):
        return self._icon_name
    def set_icon_name(self, value):
        self._icon_name = value
    icon_name = property(get_icon_name, set_icon_name)
```

You need to come up with custom field type for each form field type you use. Here is how it's done with IntegerField. Your custom field class needs to inherit from the original django form field class (IntegerField, in this case) and the *IconName* class.

```
class CustomIntegerField(IntegerField, IconName):
    pass
```

After you have defined all of the custom form field types that your form requires, update your form with them. Next, you need to initialize the `icon_name` for each form field in the form's `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['integer'].icon_name = 'icon-home'
    ...
```

In your template, you can do:

```
{% for item in form.visible_fields %}
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="{{ item.name }}">{{ item.label }}</label>
  <div class="controls">
    {% if item.field.icon_name %}
      <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="{{ item.field.icon_name }}"></i></span>
    {% endif %}
      {{ item }}
      <p class="help-block">{{ item.help_text }}</p>
    {% if item.field.icon_name %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have not tried this myself but it should work (assuming I understand you correctly)

Comment: Seems to be a good solution for my problem. It clearly adds a property on fields and uses it in templates. I'll try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I made few minor tweaks to your solution : the icon_name can be accessed in the template with `item.field.icon_name` rather than `item.icon_name`, and the form's `__init__()` was lacking the forms.Form initialization (`super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`), which creates the form's fields dict. I've edited your response. Many many thanks for your work on my problem !!!!!

Comment: @Labarbiche - Glad that I could be of a help to your question. You even managed to pick out and fix the pieces that I had missed. That's great! Happy Django'ing

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I'm just starting with Python and Django.

See if this will help you get started:

```
class MyCustomTextInput(forms.widgets.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        original_html = super(MyCustomRender,self).render(name, value, attrs)
        icon_html = "<img src='/img.png' />"
        return "%s%s" % (icon_html,original_html)

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    myfield = MyCustomTextInput()
```

I believe this would produce output similar to:

```
<img src='/img.png' /><input type="text" ... />
```

Take a look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I think it is not very practical to have the html tweaked in the form itself. I prefer a solution where html is tweaked in templates.

Answer (score -2):

Django comes by default with a simple renderer.

from django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/):

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

As for the use of custom image, Javascript would be a solution if your form is dynamic. A form model is not, since it is just a representation designed to create fomrs efficently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer the question: how do I add extra infos in forms and use them in templates.

Comment: @Labarbiche Well, a form is not designed to generate outside-form code. It really is just a representation. You can customize aspect of the generated field via [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) You could maybe use a image by typing a <img> tag in label? I don't know.

Comment: Yes you are totally right, forms should not handle html. I guess I must clarify what I want to do: Using Twister bootstrap, I want to have a 'prepend' icon for some of my fields, using such html code: `<div class="input-prepend">
<span class="add-on">
<i class="icon-envelope"></i>
</span>
<input id="inputIcon" class="span2" type="text">
</div>`

Comment: (see [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)) So I want to send that 'icon-envelope' to the template system, thus giving the template writer the choice on how using it (add a img tag, a bootstrap css'ed tag...)